# SetFields in Mongo C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

I'm using C# mongo driver and I have users collection like below,

```
 public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateField Date { get; set; }

    /*
     * Some more properties
     */

    public List<string> Slugs { get; set; } //I just need to return this property

}
```

I'm writing a query in which it just returns me the slugs property. 
To do this i'm trying to use `SetFields(...)` method from the mongo driver. SetFields returns the cursor of the `User` type i'm expecting something to be of my `Slugs` property type so that I don't return whole set of properties when i just need one. 
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. You can use the aggregation framework's [projection operator `$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to change the structure of the data, but I wouldn't do that for two reasons:

1. MongoDB generally tries to preserve the structure unless you force it to, particularly *because* it makes it easier to work with statically typed languages (the old object/relational mismatch: SQL queries don't 'answer' in users or blog post, but some wild Chimaera of properties collected from various tables, which might require additional DTOs depending on the query itself, which is all a bit ugly).
2. Aggregation framework queries are a bit more complicated and a bit slower, and I wouldn't let the urge to do some micro-optimization dictate a lot of unnecessary complexity.

After all, omitting a few fields is a micro-optimization already (setting index covered queries aside), but on the client-side the cost of empty fields should be next to none.

Comment: Here, i'm not changing the structure of the data but just want a subset of it but i see SetFields in c# mongo driver returns cusor of type of class. so will that add to its performance

Comment: Not sure what you're saying. `SetFields` doesn't change the return type, and not populated fields aren't particularly expensive.

Comment: i mentioned in my question what i'm expecting from set fields

Comment: Well, like I wrote, `SetFields` doesn't change the type, your expectation is wrong. You can use LINQ-to-Objects' `Select(p => p.Slugs)` which will return an `IEnumerable<List<string>>`, but be careful that operations on an `IEnumerable` could be signficantly slower than on a `MongoCursor` (e.g., `Count()`: The `IEnumerable` extension method will de-serialize the entire result set, whereas `MongoCursor` will simply ask the DB for the count).